# Seeking a multiple text field Cocoa control like in Address Book

Tags: cocoa

I'm looking to make a view similar to Addreess Book in editing mode, where there are fields arranged in a table, only the selected one showing a border, and with the plus and minus buttons to add/remove rows. Anyone know if there's an open source implementation of such a control, before i go and roll my own?